# Jenkins zip utility step zipping only root folder files

Tags: jenkins, zip, jenkins-plugins

```
zip archive: false, dir:sourceFolder, glob: '', zipFile: "target.zip";
```

The above command is zipping only files of the source folder but not the files of subfolders. Thanks in Advance for suggestions.

```
sourceFolder
 -a.txt
 -b.txt
 -subFold1
    -c.txt
```

When I extract the zip I am not able to see subfolder files like c.txt in the above

Comment: It works perfectly for me using the same parameters as you. I noticed that your `sourceFolder` is not quoted, though.

Comment: That is a variable which has a quoted string as value. The problem got resolved. Though It seems funny, I gave the sourceFolder as  SOURCE instead of Source. I changed to source, the exact name. It started working

Comment: that's really weird. What file system does your Jenkins use?

Comment: Yes. Running on Windows node

Comment: OK, that's less disturbing to me .